# How do I match tokens starting with "?" in pegjs

Tags: javascript, regex, grammar, pegjs

I have to match tokens like this using pegjs:

```
?xxx ?yyy
```

I would have thought this would work :

```
variable 
   = str:?[a-z]+ {  console.log('---->>>',str); return str.join(""); }
```

When I parse the source I get and error:

> Object ? has no method 'join'

This is because the `str` variable is not an array of the matched tokens... Any idea how this should be done?

Comment: Are you sure this is a real copy and past of the rule, because I would expect that the pegjs would already throw an error when parsing the grammar as `str:?[a-z]+` itself is not currect.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. It was str[?][a-z]+ ... I copied from an older/wrong copy of the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either group literals together:

```
variable 
    = str:("?"[a-z]+)
```

in which case `str` will be `["?",["a","b","c"]]` for `?abc`, or, if `?` is not necessarily the first char, just include it in the class:

```
variable 
    = str:[?a-z]+
```

then you'll get a normal array `["?","a","b","c"]`.